# Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)

Tags: node.js, linux, sass, ionic3

using ionic serve in ionic v3 project on ubuntu ... it's giving below error -

> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux
>   64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64) For more information on which
>   environments are supported please see:
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.5.3
>       at module.exports (/usr/share/tour/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
>       at Object. (/usr/share/ionic/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
>       at Object. (/usr/share/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/core/bundle-components.js:6:16)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First confirm how many versions you have installed -

```
npm ls node-sass
```

If you only see one node-sass and then run the following to rebuild the binary

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: The same error as the above question.
It's worked by removing node_modules and ***.lock file and installed it again.

Answer (score 6):

- If you use npm :

You can delete node_modules and package-lock.json

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

And rebuild

```
npm install
```

- If you use  yarn

You can delete node_modules and yarn.lock

```
rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock
```

And rebuild

```
yarn
```

Comment: Worked by changing yarn.lock file and add Integrity.

Comment: Can you explain why you are deleting the lock files in your answer? The lock files are there to "lock" the versions.  Deleting them can cause many other dependency issues, especially for old projects.

Comment: Sometimes, my lock file wasn't updated, so I had to remove lock to re-generated it.
And rebuild doesn't work fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use Node 14.

I used NVM to have both Node 16 and Node 14 and I did `nvm use 14`, then the install worked.

None of the other answers worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to 1st)  `nvm install 12`  then `nvm use 12` finally `npm rebuild node-sass`